# HTML5 canvas, convert canvas to PDF with jspdf.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas, jspdf

I am trying to convert HTML5 canvas to PDF in JavaScript but I get a black background PDF. I tried to change the background color but still get black. The following is code I am trying:

```
Canvas = document.getElementById("chart");
Context = Canvas.getContext("2d");

var imgData = Canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape');
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 1350, 750);
pdf.save('download.pdf');
```

If you have any idea, I'd appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 14):

A good approach is to use combination of jspdf.js and html2canvas. I have made a jsfiddle for you.

```
 <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas> 
      <button id="download">Download Pdf</button>
```

'

```
        html2canvas($("#canvas"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/png');              
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
            }
        });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpaul/p4s5k59s/5/

Comment: Why is it a good approach to use a combination of html2canvas with jspdf. he already has a canvas. Same is my case. I am using the same code you have in onrendered, but since I already have a canvas I am not using html2canvas.

Comment: That's a good question. It was just an experience. Few months ago, when I was working on this,  I found that jspdf.js itself does not give consistent result for Flot graphs. Using html2canvas solved my problem. To be honest, I did not investigate the internal code of these libraries. Oh I remember, Flot graphs was adding other HTML elements   with Canvas. If it is solely canvas, then Jspdf is probably enough.

Answer (score 3):

One very simple solution is that you are saving the image as jpeg.  Saving instead as png works fine for my application.  Of note, [Blizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731947/html5-canvas-convert-canvas-to-pdf-with-jspdf-js)'s response also includes the print as png, and also produces non-black fill for transparent layers in the canvas.

```
  var canvas = event.context.canvas;
  var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

*instead of*

```
  var canvas = event.context.canvas;
  var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, e.g. the first time when i create a pdf the canvas image is ok, but all the other next, came out black. No picture!

The workaround i found is as follows: after each call to pdf.addImage() i redraw the picture in the canvas.  It works now fine for me.

**EDIT:** As requested, here some more details:

Let say i have a canvas drawing function like this (just an example, it doesn't matter):

```
function drawCanvas(cv) {
  for(var i=0; i<cv.height; i++) {
    for(var j=0, d=0; j<cv.width; j++) {
      cv.data[d] = 0xff0000;
      d += 4;
    }
  }
}
```

I had to fix my printing function as follows:

```
var cv=document.getElementById('canvas');
printPDF(cv) {
    var imgData=cv.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    var doc=new jsPDF("p","mm","a4");
    doc.addImage(imgData,'JPEG',15,40,180,180);
    drawCanvas(cv); // <--- this line is needed, draw again
}
drawCanvas(cv); // <--- draw my image to the canvas, ok
printPDF(cv); // first time is fine
printPDF(cv); // second time without repaint would be black
```

I admit, i did'nt investigate further, just happy that this works.

Comment: Could you expound on `after each call to pdf.addImage() i redraw the picture in the canvas`? It would be very helpful if you could share some code.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to *set* the desired background color on the `canvas` before getting the `data`. Then, you need to draw `jpeg` image on the `canvas`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I set backgroud color like Canvas.style.color = "white" but still black.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the format JPEG to PNG

```
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 1350, 750);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending your answer bit more for other fellow programmers; in order to understand how exactly it helps to solve the problem.