# Does jsPDF allow for custom document sizes such as single labels?

Tags: jspdf

I am trying to create pdf with a single label to print to a Brother PL-7 label printer.

I found jsPDF that is able to generate a PDF, however two problems.

1. I can't seem to specify the document to a custom size.
2. I am unsure of how to put the bar code I have in a canvas generated by jsBarcode into the PDF.

How can I create a single label size PDF document with a bar code included on it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found this fix on their github issues page in regards to the first problem:

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/372

worked for me perfectly once the that code was altered.

I know a lot less about how what exactly jsBarcode generates, but if it is generating a canvas file as you mentioned in your question, it can be converted into a png/jpeg and then be fed into jsPDF. See [HTML5 canvas, convert canvas to PDF with jspdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731947/html5-canvas-convert-canvas-to-pdf-with-jspdf-js).